# QBXML : Can there be multiple credit/debit line items in a journal entry query response?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I am retrieving the journal entries and trying to determine whether there will only ever be one JournalCreditLine node and one JournalDebitLine node per JournalEntryRet or if there could be multiple line entries.

EDIT:

I have added multiple journal entries in one place with the same timestamp, but I always get multiple `<JournalEntryRet>` and never multiple `<JournalDebitLine>` or `<JournalCreditLine>`

Query I am sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <JournalEntryQueryRq requestID="[request id from DB]"> 
    <IncludeLineItems>1</IncludeLineItems>
    </JournalEntryQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>';
```

Example Response (with all customer data removed):

[data]
                [data]
                [data]
                [data]
                [data]
                [data]
                [data]
                [data]
                
                    [data]
                    
                        [data]
                        [data]
                    
                    [data]
                    [data]
                
                
                    [data]
                    
                        [data]
                        [data]
                    
                    [data]
                    [data]

```
        <JournalEntryRet>
            <TxnID>[data]</TxnID>
            <TimeCreated>[data]</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>[data]</TimeModified>
            <EditSequence>[data]</EditSequence>
            <TxnNumber>[data]</TxnNumber>
            <TxnDate>[data]</TxnDate>
            <RefNumber>[data]</RefNumber>
            <IsAdjustment>[data]</IsAdjustment>
            <JournalDebitLine>
                <TxnLineID>[data]</TxnLineID>
                <AccountRef>
                    <ListID>[data]</ListID>
                    <FullName>[data]</FullName>
                </AccountRef>
                <Amount>[data]</Amount>
                <Memo>[data]</Memo>
            </JournalDebitLine>
            <JournalCreditLine>
                <TxnLineID>[data]</TxnLineID>
                <AccountRef>
                    <ListID>[data]</ListID>
                    <FullName>[data]</FullName>
                </AccountRef>
                <Amount>[data]</Amount>
                <Memo>[data]</Memo>
            </JournalCreditLine>
        </JournalEntryRet>

        <!-- more JournalEntryRet nodes -->
        </JournalEntryQueryRs>
    </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple journal credit lines, and multiple journal debit lines, in a single JournalEntry object. This mirrors the behavior of the QuickBooks GUI.

The business rule is that the sum of all credit lines must equal the sum of all debit lines.

Comment: Is this response referencing IIPP-IA QBO V3, QBXML or both? I have tried to put data into QB to get multiple credit/debit lines, but always end up with multiple JournalEntryRet nodes, each with one credit/debit line. I am working with QBXML, not IIPP-IA QBO V3

Comment: This is reference to BOTH. Post your qbXML request.